# Spring Boot - Consider defining a bean of type 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-micrometer

I've spent a few days and could not get it working, new to instrumentation in spring. I have attached picture of my project dependency tree it shows both micrometer-core and spring-boot-starter-actuator.

Error- Consider defining a bean of type 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' in your configuration.

Adding my application.yml config

```
management:
 endpoints:
  web:
   exposure:
    include: info, health, loggers, prometheus
 metrics:
  web:
   server:
    request:
      autotime:
        percentiles: 0.50,0.75,0.95,0.99
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Micrometer collection facility is included in Spring Boot 2's Actuator. You don't need to add new if you are adding new. With Boot 2.7.0, 1.8. version is compatible, so try with 1.8 micrometer instead.

Add below configuration to create the Bean type MeterRegistry. You need to create the MeterRegistry instance inside this bean.

```html
@Configuration
public class MyMetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistry meterRegistry() {
        // Create and configure the MeterRegistry instance here
        return /* Your MeterRegistry instance */;
    }
}
```

Comment: My boot version is 2.7.10 and with that 1.9 is compatible

Comment: Thanks. Its clear if you can specify the boot versions. Try registering the bean like I said above. It should work. Let me know once you tried.

Comment: we can not configure MeterRegistry instance directly.. it is of "protected" type..

Comment: Ok, Since the question you asked doesn't show your code, I will route you to go with the check list in https://www.java67.com/2023/03/how-to-fix-consider-defining-bean-of.html   and, check this for reference https://github.com/bclozel/issues-dashboard/issues/3   - add @SpringBootApplication annotation as well. Let me know how this goes!!

Comment: the same code working in intellij and not in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

According to SpringBoot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics) :

> Spring Boot auto-configures a composite MeterRegistry and adds a registry to the composite for each of the supported implementations that it finds on the classpath. Having a dependency on micrometer-registry-{system} in your runtime classpath is enough for Spring Boot to configure the registry.

Do you have your application annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` (or at least `@EnableAutoConfiguration`) (doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/htmlsingle/#using.using-the-springbootapplication-annotation))

> Many Spring Boot developers like their apps to use auto-configuration, component scan and be able to define extra configuration on their "application class". A single @SpringBootApplication annotation can be used to enable those three features, that is:
>
> - @EnableAutoConfiguration: enable Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism
> - @ComponentScan: enable @Component scan on the package where the application is located (see the best practices)
> - @SpringBootConfiguration: enable registration of extra beans in the context or the import of additional configuration classes. An alternative to Spring’s standard @Configuration that aids configuration detection in your integration tests.

Comment: Yes  my application is annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: When did you get that exception ? In main app ? In unit test ?

Comment: in main app while trying to run the application itself

Comment: Could you share the complete stacktrace ? Thanks